# Shutdown Spring Application after camel route has sent data

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm using Camel in a Spring Application. What I need is to properly shut down my Application after camel has sent all his data. Basically camel has to read a file, split it in rows and send each row as kafka massage.
How can I shutdown my application after camel has finished to send all messages?
Here is my route:

```
public class Router extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    // Kafka Producer
    from("file:{{file.dir}}?fileName={{file.name}}&noop=true")
            .split(body().tokenize("\r\n|\n")).streaming()
            .to("kafka:{{kafka.topic}}?brokers={{spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers}}");
}
}
```

Comment: An [onCompletion](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/oncompletion.html) callback can close the Spring ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you can call System.exit command

```
 from("file:{{file.dir}}?fileName={{file.name}}&noop=true").routeId("fileconsumer")
            .split(body().tokenize("\r\n|\n")).streaming()
            .to("kafka:{{kafka.topic}}?brokers={{spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers}}")
            .process(exchange -> System.exit(0));
```

or you can stop camel route

```
CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
      context.stopRoute("fileconsumer");
```